# selenium create a delay before selecting button by name

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to target a button that contains the name ="loginButton", and click the element after loading etc so it doesnt click on the loading spinner. How do I go about this webdriverwait targetting the name element?

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((find_element_by_name('loginButton'), "loginButton"))).click()
```

Comment: If you can't click it, it doesn't click it... 
If the delay is fixed you can use the time.sleep (yourdelay) function.

Comment: its a button so it definitely clicks, question is how do i go about doing the webdriverwait delay? is my code correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium wait for element to be clickable python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083974/selenium-wait-for-element-to-be-clickable-python)

Comment: prophet has the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost correct.
For the provided example try using following code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "loginButton")))

element.click();
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110008/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-clickable-not-working) for more explanations